# How do touch typists navigate in vi?

Tags: editor, keyboard, navigation, vi, touch-typing

I'm learning vi, as I appreciate the vast possibilities of the editor, and have to use a plain-text editor for my current project. In many tutorials I have read that it is recommended to use the keys "h", "j", "k" and "l" instead of the arrow keys, for the sake of speed.

However, as a touch typist, my fingers are normally in the default position of a, s, d, f (left hand) and j, k, l and ö (right hand [german keyboard]). Navigating in vi requires effectively to place the right hand in the default position of h, j, k and l. This makes writing text correctly hard, as I notice constantly that I start to type text, when my right hand is in the "vi right hand position" instead of the "touch-typing right hand position".

As a touch typist, have you adapted your hand memory so that you have switch the position depending on the vi mode, or have you found some other solution? I would appreciate experiences and tips from experienced touch typists using vi.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I still keep my fingers on the home keys for touch typing, and just reach for the keys I want. My index finger is used for both h and j. I'm not often switching between h and j anyway, so it doesn't slow me down.

I find I use w, b, 0, f and / to navigate though, not so much with h, j, k and l.

BTW. I found it really hard to write this message into the browser text box. When typing about vi keys, my fingers naturally wanted to use them. Please excuse any extraneous characters :-)

Comment: I do pretty much the same thing.  I find that reaching for the Esc key slows me down a lot more than using my left index finger for both h and j.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I'll try to establish this habit.

Comment: @William: D'oh!  I was thinking "left pinky" when writing the bit about the Esc key and it came out all wrong. :)

Comment: For those getting stuck on the escape key - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397229/reaching-up-to-hit-the-escape-key-sucks-especially-in-vim

Comment: Six days after adopting this practice, I can say it works very well.

Comment: I recommend that if you were about to move backwards, often F, search backwards in the current line, would be equally effective.